# Wordpress API - link to full post details from list of posts

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-json-api

I have installed the Wordpress API onto on of our company websites so that we can retrieve data from it to display on a new company website. With regards to grabbing and displaying the initial data all works fine (posts from a specific category from the original website onto a specific page on the new website).

This is for a events that are input onto a 'whats on' page on the existing website that take place at a bar/restaurant. The new site is purely dedicated to the events and to save having to add/amend the events on both sites we thought it best to use the API.

To retrieve the full listing of events (which works) I use:

```
$response = wp_remote_get( 'http://restuarantdomain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[category_name]=live-events&per_page=50' );
```

I also know that to display an individual post I need to use:

```
$response = wp_remote_get( 'http://restaurantdomain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[name]=event_name );
```

What I can't work out how to do is create a 'friendly' url on the new site that will then go to a page that calls the function to get the individual post details.

For example I want the url http://eventdomain.com/whats-on/event-name (in the list of event posts grabbed through the 1st API call above) to go to the page What's On and on that page use the event-name from the url as the parameter in the 2nd API call above. But Wordpress just looks for the category and post name due to the format of the url which don't exist so I just get a 404.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can use copy of original database for new project by just change of  home url and admin url . Try this.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use a copy of the original database otherwise I would have done that, that is not the purpose of me using the API. This a a different website for another part of the business with one are the same so rather than input it twice each time there are new posts we only have to add or update it on one site.

Comment: I think its difficult to manage..One only way for this,  you  should retreive the post data from original website database by mysql connection query from wp_post and wp_postmeta . At here , You have done all thing manully like delete, add post etc @emdav43  . As your requirement , this thing only one way . If you not satisfy then please Edit your question and explain it clearly Dear

Comment: Sorry but I don't think you understand what I am trying to do (and maybe I haven't explained it clearly enough but I don't know how else to do so)

Answer (score 0):

You must create your custom Endpoints.

for instance, if you want to filter all posts within a particular category you should do this

```
function my_cat_func( $data ) {
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'cat' => $data['id'],
    ) );

    if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
        return null;
    }

    return $posts[0]->post_title;
}
```

then you must add an action to register your endpoint call

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v2', '/categoy/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_cat_func',
    ) );
} );
```

then you will get something like this

```
http://example.com/wp-json/myplugin/v2/categoy/(?P<id>\d+)
```

for more information and better understanding, I suggest you reading this reference: 
http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/

This article also can give you more example: https://webdevstudios.com/2015/07/09/creating-simple-json-endpoint-wordpress/
and 
https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-rest-api-customizing-endpoints-adding-new-ones/

Note: I wrote this code on the fly, that should need more efforts to work.

Comment: Thank you for your help Majid, I think I get the idea but will read up further through your suggested links tomorrow when my brain is less frazzled.

Comment: Great if you worked on that and see it's working for you, please leave a comment here and accept this answer, hope it will help others later.